# How can I update the size of a button after adding it to a table?

Tags: libgdx

I have a table that acts as the HUD for my game. It features a bar (as a text button) and label showing how much shields are left. So I initially add the shield bar to the table, with the cell set at a certain size to correspond to maximum width of the shield bar when shields are at 100%.

I then want to be able to change the width of the shield bar to show shields dropping but my code doesn't seem work. Is anyone able to tell me how I change the size of a button after having added it to a table and having added it to the stage?

```
// Add shield bar and label to table
table.add(enemyShieldBar).align(Align.right).colspan(2).expandX();
table.add(enemyshieldLabel);
table.add(fillerLabel).row();

// Attempt to update the label and button size
enemyshieldLabel.setText("new text ");
enemyShieldBar.setSize(5,5);
```

Answer (score -3):

you can use this, just use width and height methods.

```
table.add(enemyshieldLabel).width(300).height(500).align(Ali.......
```